How to show that the double cover of the circle as an affine algebraic set is étale?
I am used to the notion of an étale map in topology, which is simply a map which is a local homeomorphism. I have been presented with the following definition of an étale map of commutative rings:
A ring map $f: A \to B$ is called étale if the following conditions hold:

$B$ is a finitely presented $A$-algebra

For all rings $C$, nilpotent ideals $N$ and commutative diagrams
$$
\require{HTML}
\newcommand{\rotate}[2]{\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(#2deg)}{#1}}
\newcommand\quotient[2]{{^{\Large #1}}/{_{ \Large #2}}}
\begin{array}{ccc}
A & \overset{f}{\rightarrow} & B \\
{\scriptstyle g} \downarrow & & \downarrow {\scriptstyle h} \\
C & \underset{q}{\rightarrow} & \quotient{C}{N} \\
\end{array}
$$
there exists a unique map $k: B \to C$ making the following diagram commute:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
A & \overset{f}{\rightarrow} & B \\
{\scriptstyle g} \downarrow & \overset{\exists ! k}{\rotate{\dashrightarrow}{135}} & \downarrow {\scriptstyle h} \\
C & \underset{q}{\rightarrow} & \quotient{C}{N} \\
\end{array}
$$


I would like to check this condition in a concrete example.
Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field with $\operatorname{char} K \neq 2$. Let $A = \quotient{K[z, \ w]}{\langle z^2 \ + \ w^2 \ - \ 1 \rangle}$ and $B = \quotient{K[x, \ y]}{\langle x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ - \ 1 \rangle}$. I know that these are isomorphic, but for the purpose of this question, I would like to be able to distinguish between them. Now consider the ring map
$$
\varphi: A \to B, \\
z \mapsto x^2 - y^2, \\
w \mapsto 2xy
$$
Indeed, we have
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
(x^2 - y^2)^2 + (2xy)^2 & = & x^4 - 2x^2y^2 + y^4 + 4x^2y^2 \\
& = & x^4 + 2x^2y^2 + y^4 \\
& = & (x^2 + y^2)^2 \\
& = & 1^2 \\
& = & 1 \\
\end{array}
$$
This shows that $\varphi$ is well-defined.
Geometrically, $A$ and $B$ correspond to circles and $\varphi$ corresponds to the squaring map, which is the double cover from the circle to itself. Geometrically, this should be an étale map.
How can we use the above definition to show that the ring map $\varphi: A \to B$ is étale?

We consider the endomorphism $\varphi : k[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1) \to k[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$, $x \to x^2-y^2$, $y \to 2xy$. It is easier to work with an isomorphic endomorphism.
After substituting $y=is$ we see $k[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1) \cong k[x,s]/(x^2-s^2-1)$. After writing $x^2-s^2=(x+s)(x-s)$ and substituting $x+s=u$, $x-s=v$ we get $\cong k[u,v]/(uv-1) \cong k[u,u^{-1}]$. The isomorphism
$$\alpha : k[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1) \xrightarrow{~\sim~} k[u,u^{-1}]$$
is given by $\alpha(x) = (u+u^{-1})/2$ and $\alpha(y) = i(u-u^{-1})/2$. The inverse is given by $\alpha^{-1}(u) = x-iy$. Now we may just compute $\varphi' := \alpha \circ \varphi \circ \alpha^{-1}$:
$$\begin{align*}
\varphi'(u) & = \alpha(\varphi(x-iy))) \\
& = \alpha(x^2-y^2 - 2xyi) \\
& = \alpha((x-iy)^2) \\
& = \alpha(x-iy)^2 \\
& = u^2.
\end{align*}$$
Therefore, it is enough to consider endomorphism
$$\varphi' : k[u,u^{-1}] \to k[u,u^{-1}], \quad u \mapsto u^2.$$
It is clearly of finite presentation. To show that it is formally étale, consider a commutative ring $C$ with a nilpotent ideal $N$ and a commutative diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
k[u,u^{-1}] @>{\varphi'}>> k[u,u^{-1}] \\
@VVV @VVV \\
C @>>> C/N
\end{CD}$$
We need to find a unique homomorphism $k[u,u^{-1}] \to C$ from the top right to the lower left that makes the diagram commute.
The given vertical map on the left makes $C$ a commutative $k$-algebra. The rest then corresponds to an invertible element $a \in C$ and an invertible element $[b] \in C/N$ such that $a$ maps to $[b]^2$ in $C/N$. We can lift $[b]$ to an invertible element $b \in C$ (remember that ($\ast$) "invertible + nilpotent = invertible"), and commutativity tells us
$$a \equiv b^2 \bmod N.$$
Our goal is to show that there is a unique invertible element $c \in C$ such that $a = c^2$ and $b \equiv c \bmod N$.
By a simple substitution, the definition of $\bmod N$ and another application of ($\ast$), this problem is equivalent to the following one: For every invertible element $b$ and every $n \in N$ we need to find a unique element $m \in N$ with
$$b^2 + n = (b + m)^2.$$
By dividing by $b^2$ and another simple substitution, we may reduce to the case $b=1$. Thus, for every $n \in N$ we need to find a unique $m \in N$ with
$$1 + n = (1 + m)^2.$$
Notice that we have a problem here when, say, $2=0$, since we cannot expect to solve $n = m^2$. But $2$ is invertible in our case.
To show existence of $m$, the idea (see also here) is to use the binomial series
$$(1+T)^{1/2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{k} T^k$$
in $\mathbb{Q}[[T]]$. Since $\binom{1/2}{k}$ has only powers of $2$ in the denominator, the equation already holds in $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]\, [[T]]$. Since $2$ is invertible in $C$ and $n$ is nilpotent, there is homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]\, [[T]] \to C$ mapping $T \mapsto n$. Therefore,
$$(1+n)^{1/2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{k} n^k$$
holds in $C$ (notice that this sum is finite), and
$$m := \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{k} n^k$$
does the job.
To show that a nilpotent $m$ is uniquely determined by $1+n = (1+m)^2$, notice that this is equivalent to
$$m = \frac{1}{2} (n - m^2)$$
Substitute $m$ in $m^2$ by this formula, again and again:
$$m = \frac{1}{2} (n - \frac{1}{4} (n - m^2)^2) = \frac{1}{2} (n - \frac{1}{4} (n - \frac{1}{4}(n - m^2)^2)^2) = \cdots $$
In each step, the minimal degree of a monomial that appears in the expression and has some $m$ in it grows by $1$. Since $n,m$ are nilpotent, at some point these monomials vanish, meaning we are left with a formula of $m$ which only depends on $n$. Thus, $m$ is unique.
The same proof shows that $k[u,u^{-1}] \to k[u,u^{-1}]$, $u \mapsto u^d$ is étale for $d \geq 1$ when $d \in k^{\times}$. Even more generally, we have the so-called standard étale maps $R \to R[X]_g/(f)$, where $R$ is any commutative ring, $f,g \in R[X]$ such that $f$ is monic and $f'$ is invertible in $R[X]_g/(f)$. In our case, $R = k[u,u^{-1}]$, $g = 1$, $f = X^d-u$, and indeed $f' = d X^{d-1}$ is invertible since $d$ and $X$ are invertible. It is an important result (Stacks/00UE) that every étale map is "built" from standard étale maps.
